# SQL command for getting a specific pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, sqlcommand

I have a table sample with column 'observations':

[image]

Please help with the SQL command to get the following 'cumulative multiplication' output:

```
2
6
30
300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by obs) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select obs as prod, seqnum
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.prod * tt.obs, tt.seqnum
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Another uses arithmetic to implement a "product" window function:

```
select t.*,
       exp(sum(log(obs)) over (order by obs))
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e2bd6b60f2d05f9355db8169facbdcc) is a db<>fiddle.